# CakePHP Calling Component Constructor with argument

Tags: constructor, components, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 version and created a component as GoogleApiComponent as follows.

```
class GoogleApiComponent extends Component {
  public $client;
  public $analytics;
  function __construct($prompt = null) {
      $this->client = new apiClient();
      $this->client->setApprovalPrompt($prompt);
      $this->analytics = new apiAnalyticsService($this->client);
  }
```

}

Then in AppController, I included the above component.

```
public $components = array('GoogleApi');
```

After an user logs in, I have to check some conditions in beforeFilter() method of AppController and according to that conditions I have to change the argument of GoogleAPiComponent Constructor.
So How this get it done? the work is more appreciable..

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `$settings` array to your components.

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#configuring-components

Inside your component you can access the array via `$this->settings`